# Typescript: initialize empty array when using extends Array<T>

Tags: typescript

I am trying to add a method which would belong to a class extending Arrays of `device` with Typescript (3.7.5).

```js
export class devices extends Array<device> {
    constructor(items?:Array<device>) {
        super(...items);
    }

    getDeviceByUid(uid: number): device {
        return this.filter(elmt => elmt.uid == uid)[0];
    }
}
```

But I also need to be able to declare and define an empty array, like I would do with a normal array:

`unfilteredDeviceList: devices = []; //error : Property 'getDeviceByUid' is missing in type 'undefined[]' but required in type 'devices'.`

So I tried like so:
`unfilteredDeviceList: devices = new devices();`

I get no compile time errors when doing the latest, but in runtime : `Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: super is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))`

What is the way to declare and define an extended empty array, or what should I change in the constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the constructor implementation this way should work:

```
class devices extends Array<device> {
    constructor(items?:Array<device>) {
        super();

        if (items) {
            this.push(...items);
        }
    }

    getDeviceByUid(uid: number): device {
        return this.filter(elmt => elmt.uid == uid)[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, however now I'm getting `TypeError: Found non-callable @@iterator` when using it in Angular. It seems that Angular passes a `number` to the constructor when doing some refreshes...
I don't understand why

Answer (score 1):

Guess you now initialize by `const arr: devices = new devices([])`